# citroen c5 2007, AL4, noise when on R

Tags: transmission, citroen

Sometimes when i change to Reverse, there is strange noise from inside of the car, whats possible cause?
the transmission is auto, AL4, and the noise is even if i m not moving(brake pedal)

Comment: Does it have auto or manual transmission?  Does it make the noise before or after the car moves?

Comment: added, see my edits

Comment: Can you describe the noise or make a video and post a link to it.  Anything to better describe your issues increases your chances of a solution being put forth   :-)   cheers!